# Matrix concatenation notation

Tags: matrices, notation

Is there any symbolic manner to represent the concatenation of matrices row or column-wise? Briefness is appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Maybe $(\mathbf{A}^{\intercal} \mid \mathbf{B}^{\intercal})^{\intercal}$.

Comment: That would work I guess, but I think $\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}$ would be simpler and probably just as clear, if not clearer.

Comment: Much appreciated.